# How to change the colour of back button?

Tags: ios, button, colors

I have a map with just a back button at the top of the screen. For some reason it wont change colour for me. This is the code that I have in the delegate to change the other back button in the delegate.

`UIBarButtonItem *barButtonAppearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearance];
            [barButtonAppearance setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To change the text color of a single button you might set an attributed string as its title:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]};
[button setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To change the color of all buttons in your navigation bar try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

The last one will also change the tint color if you have an image instead of text.

Both methods are tested unter iOS7.